# Connecting to Remote Server MySQL Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, remote-access

I'm attempting to connect to a remote server, which I'll refer to as machine A. I've created a user following the instructions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html)

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
      WITH GRANT OPTION;
CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
      WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

On machine A I can run the command

```
mysql -u monty -h website.com -p
```

This connects to sql with no problem. However, when attempting to do this from some machine B I receive the error:

> ```
> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'website.com' (113)
> ```

I've also commented out the following line:

```
# bind-address      = 127.0.0.1
```

in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. Still no luck connecting from a remote connection. Any obvious things that I might be missing? Any feedback as always is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the server listening on port 3306?  You can check by doing a `netstat -ln`.  See if 3306 is listed at all.  If it is, check what IP it's listening on.  If it's not then you know the problem is it's not listening at all or on a different port.

Comment: After running netstat -ln, port 3306 is listed as : 
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN
any feedback on what that means?

Comment: That means it's listening on all network interfaces.  Assuming `website.com` is pointing to an IP that corresponds to that server you shouldn't have any problems.  Make sure you flushed privileges, also try checking the mysql error log for any other hints of what could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's your GRANT that needs fixing.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
```

Might need to be

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'website.com'
```

You're going to want to make sure things are secure though.
It's usually best practice to try not to allow outside mysql connects that aren't from localhost.

Comment: Well according to the tutorial, you must do both:

"It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect from anywhere as monty. Without the localhost account, the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order."

Comment: As for the security side of things, I have a program that anyone can download say. Through this program I want to have the user upload content to a database. Is there another safer method that I could employ? Thanks again.

Comment: Ah ok, so if you're using a shared hosting service they might have things locked down a little bit. 
One way to secure things down is to make an API that your application can connect to and then that API will connect to the database locally.  This won't save you from everything but it allows you to control it a little better.

Comment: I have root access to the host machine, so any modifications I should be able to make. Are there any good web resources for creating an API you could recommend? Also, I certainly want to make sure this issue is resolved first before proceeding to construct the API and running into the same problem. Any insights?

Comment: in case of emergency: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'` will allow connection from anywhere

Comment: You can google "How to create an API" and you'll find a ton of stuff. This one looks pretty good http://particletree.com/features/how-to-add-an-api-to-your-web-service/.  I'm more partial to JSON personally as opposed to XML. Also, an API will be connection locally since it runs off the same server. So it should resolve this problem in a way. You will still want to make sure that things are locked down though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 'website.com' address cannot be resolved from the machine B. Please try to connect the MySQL server using the IP address of machine A, i.e.:

```
mysql -u monty -h x.x.x.x -p
```

If it will work, please make sure you mapped the IP address of the machine A to the name 'website.com' correctly.

Comment: No luck here either. Obviously on machine A:

mysql -u monty -h x.x.x.x -p 

works, but on machine B I still get the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please check tf the machine A is accessible from the machine B at all? I.e. try **ping x.x.x.x** where x.x.x.x is an IP address of A. Also, have you restarted the MySQL after making change in the **my.cnf** file?

Comment: I did make sure to restart MySQL after modifying the my.cnf file, but do not receive any response when pinging my server from a remote machine. Is there some modification I can make to my machine A to respond to these pings?

Comment: By the way, do you have "skip-networking" setting commented in my.cnf?

Generally, if the machine A is not available from B, most likely there's a network issue, but clearly not the MySQL configuration issue.

Unfortunately I have no information about your network configuration, and I am not the network specialist as well, so I can suggest to check only a general thing: if there any firewall is working on A, which could block the  network connections from B?

Comment: Alright, I got it so that I can ping the server (which perhaps rules out the network issue?), but it still cannot connect, as it gives the same ERROR 2003 as it did before. I'll look into the firewall as well

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the firewall was blocking the connection.

I was using CentOS 7 and was getting this error:

```
mysql -usomeuser -h192.168.194.4 -p somedb
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.194.4' (113)
```

So, I installed telnet to try and got this:

```
[root@vm3 config]# telnet 192.168.194.4 3306
Trying 192.168.194.4...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.194.4: No route to host
```

and as others noted, the error 113 is "No route to host" which is not a MySQL config issue.

I could have just opened 3306 to the world or just the one IP I was connecting from, but instead, I decided to create a new zone since it was for my ESX host's internal "hostonly" network.

On the host running MySQL (MariaDB), I ran these firewall commands:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=esxlocalhost --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=esxlocalhost --permanent --add-source=192.168.194.0/24
firewall-cmd --zone=esxlocalhost --permanent --add-port=3306/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Once that was done, I could connect on the client:
mysql -usomeuser -h192.168.194.4 -p somedb
Enter password:

And life was good