# How to connect Databse from Server in php?

Tags: php, mysql

1. My Source was on my localhost and DATABASE was on our Server, so i want 
   to connect DB with my Server.
2. while i try to connect with DB it will give an Error " Could not connect: No route to host".

   ```
    $con = mysql_connect("192.168.0.99", "root", "password") or  
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
   ```

Comment: $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or
die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

Comment: No. Don't. Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated.

Comment: Don't use myslq* function, iit's deprecated on PHP 5 and remove on PHP 7!

Comment: @Barclick Flores Velasquez but my DATABASE was on "192.168.0.99" server, and my source code was in my local, so how can i connect it with SERVER?

Comment: No route to host means it cannot connect to the machiene on 192.168.0.99. Are you sure it is accessible from your computer? Can you ping it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763519/how-to-connect-to-database-on-another-server

Comment: You need to check DB credentials like host, etc carefully and best way first try to connect database using cmd and any tools or ping host also so that you can do self verify database connectivity is reachable or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. use mysqli
2. make sure you have GRANT access on mysql

   `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'hostname'`
   so in your case you need to give permission `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.0.99'`
3. try to connect server remotely

> ```
>  mysql -u root -p -h 192.168.0.99
> Enter password:
> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
> Your MySQL connection id is 17
> Server version: 5.0.45 Source distribution
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.
>
> mysql>
> ```

Comment: while i enter the Password it will give an Error 
"ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.0.99' (113)"

Comment: @Chaudhary 13 error shows "no route to host" error.you must configure your ip address on both machines. In that case need to give permission https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488740/connecting-to-remote-server-mysql-issue

Comment: check this [link](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-grant-all-privileges-on-a-database-in-mysql/) but change localhost with your ip

Comment: @Piyush Gupta it will give an Error that "GRANT: command not found",, My DATABASE was on "192.168.0.99/phpmyadmin" server

Comment: @Chaudhary go to phpmyadmin and find user root then give privilege using https://serverfault.com/questions/565343/how-to-grant-and-revoke-rights-to-tables-using-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: @I.g.karolos but my DATABASE was on "192.168.0.99" server, and my source code was in my local, so how can i connect it with SERVER?

Comment: Yes just change the appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the IP address you put in the connection string is the IP address of your machine.

The reason this doesn't work is likely because the MySQL server is configured to only listen on the Localhost loopback IP.

So... the following should work:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

NOTE: I have changed to using mysqli instead of mysql_connect as this is no longer supported.

**If your database server is not held on your localhost then you may need to check that the server is configured to accept connections from your IP address. This setting is in the my.cnf file and is called "bind". Change this to 0.0.0.0 to accept and listen for connections from any IP address.**

Answer (score -1):

```
    const USERNAME="root";
    const PASSWORD="password";
    const HOST="localhost";
    const DB="DBName";

 private function getConnection(){
        $username = self::USERNAME;
        $password = self::PASSWORD;
        $host = self::HOST;
        $db = self::DB;
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $username, $password);
        return $connection;
    }
```